# how to take take multiple pages as input in pdfplumber?

Tags: python, pdf, pdfplumber

I am using pdfplumber to take input from a pdf file.
My question is how can I take from page 1-7 input using pdfplumber.

I'm using this code:

```
filename = "1st Year 1stSemester.pdf"
pdf = pdfplumber.open(filename)

totalpages = len(pdf.pages)
p0 = pdf.pages[0-6]

table = p0.extract_table()
table
```

I want to take input from page 1 to 7
I've also tried `p0 = pdf.pages[0,1,2,3,6]`. It also doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (0,7):
    print(filename.pages[i].extract_text)
```

To show the pages, use the for loop. Input the desired pages you want to show for example in your case you want to display the pages 1-7, just like how you count an array, it start with 0 till the last page which is 7.